# Emacs 27.1 on ubuntu 20.04 not finding any fonts

Tags: installation, fonts, emacs, ubuntu-20.04

I've just downloaded, compiled and installed emacs 27.1 on two different computers running on ubuntu 20.04.  For some reason one will give me lots of choices of fonts under Options / Set Default Font but the other machine only give me a very basic primitive set.  On the one that works correctly a nice window pops up titled "Pick a font" that has many choices and also allows me to set the size, but this does not happen on the non-working machine.  Am I missing an application to find the fonts, or do I have to do something like latex and do a "hash" to find all installed fonts? Thx. J

Answer (score 0):

Since you compiled these yourself, probably you were missing development packages on one of the machines, which has led to a more limited configuration when you ran configure as part of the build process.  Originally Emacs used the standard X font facilities, but over the years has picked up the ability to use freetype and other modern font libraries, but still has the old code as a fallback if you don't have the required libraries installed when you build it.

Comment: Thanks @JSON for that, I did some googling and found a couple of recommendations of a whole long list of dev packages and did install them.  I then reconfigured and recompiled and still have the same problem.  Any guesses as to what might be missing and/or a way to debug and figure out what is missing? Thx. J